# Providing arguments to transactions in Datastore Plus (NDB)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having trouble working out how to pass in arguments into transactions when using Datastore Plus.

Could someone please rewrite this regular-datastore example code?

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Accumulator(db.Model):
    counter = db.IntegerProperty()

def increment_counter(key, amount):
    obj = db.get(key)
    obj.counter += amount
    obj.put()

q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Accumulator")
acc = q.get()

db.run_in_transaction(increment_counter, acc.key(), 5)
```

I'm particularly interested in the datastore plus equivalent of that last line.

The [datastore plus documentation](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/document/d/1hJI0Jk4vQMIoyrfqFpWhYODHXBtxpMHHeR2hjQ9NyXY/edit?ndplr=1&pli=1)'s example code doesn't deal with arguments at all (hardcoded inside the transaction).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you can follow the example from the docs, the answer is to use a lambda (or a named helper function).  E.g.

```
yield context.transaction(lambda: increment_counter(acc.key(), 5))
```